# Jekyll. Задать другой title в layout

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Есть такая структура:

```
_layouts
  default.html
  newlayout.html
```

В корневом `_config.yml` прописан общий `title` для сайта:
`title: MyTitle1`

В `default.html` содержится `head` и другие инклюды, ничего интересного.

В `newlayout.html` содержится такая вводная:

```
---
layout: default
title: MyTitle2
---
```

Так вот, когда я пытаюсь вывести в  `default.html` `title` посредством такой команды:
`{{ page.title }}`, ничего не получается, возвращается nill, как я понимаю.

Вообще придумал такую конструкцию для использования `liquid` в `head` в `default.html`:

```
  {% if page.title %}
    {{ page.title }}
  {% else %}
    {{ site.title }}
  {% endif %}
```

Должна выводить тайлт на странице, если он указан, или же указанный тайтл в общей конфигурации сайта.
Но как я понимаю, лейаут - не страница, поэтому так нельзя?
Или всё-таки можно? То как?
Нигде о таком инфы не нашел.

Comment: В лейауте доступен контекст рендерящейся страницы. А вот можно ли делать оверрайд поля страницы в лейауте, вопрос интересный. Возможно, надо сделать другую переменную для заголовка лейаутов, не пересекающуюся со страничными?

Comment: Ещё раз, правильно ли я понимаю задачу: вы хотите определить два лейаута: `default` и `derived` (названия для примера), в которых определить разные `title` и если у страницы не определён собственный `title`, то при разных лейаутах (`default` и `derived`) у неё должен быть разный `title`. А если у страницы он есть, то заголовок из лейаутов должен игнорироваться. Похоже?

Comment: @D-side, не совсем. Хотя, может, я не так понял. Есть способ объяснить логику более понятно, ведь случая всего два: если в лейауте не указан тайтл, то выводить тайтл, который указан глобально (в `_config.yml` как переменная), через `{{ site.tite }}`. А если в лейауте прописан title, то указывать его через `{{ page.title }}`. Проблема в том, что title в лейауте просто как будто игнорируется, его как будто не существует.

Comment: @D-side, честно говоря, я сейчас просто попробовал создать переменную прям в лейауте (derived по вашему примеру если брать) с названием `lala: true`, а затем в этом же лейауте вывести её через `{{ page.lala }}`, но она не выводится... Эм, я не понимаю, почему.